RabbitMQ Nodes not joining to Cluster while deploying to Kubernetes
These are the yaml files of statefuls, headless services and config-map. Please see that secret is rightly being induced as I have checked that erlang cookie is same in all the nodes.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-master
  namespace: hi-rabbitmq
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "rabbitmq"
  serviceName: rabbitmq-headless
  replicas: 3
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: rabbitmq-data
      namespace: hi-rabbitmq
    spec:
      storageClassName: standard
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "3Gi"
  template:
    metadata:
      name: rabbitmq
      namespace: hi-rabbitmq
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: "rabbitmq-config"
        image: busybox:1.32.0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rabbitmq-config
          mountPath: /tmp/rabbitmq
        - name: rabbitmq-config-rw
          mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq
        - name: rabbitmq-cookie
          mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
        - name: rabbitmq-cookie-perm
          mountPath: /tmp/rabbitmq-cookie
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        args:
          - |
            cp /tmp/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
            cp /tmp/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
            cp /tmp/rabbitmq-cookie/.erlang.cookie /var/lib/rabbitmq
            chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
            chown 999:999 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
      volumes:
      - name: rabbitmq-config
        configMap:
          name: rabbitmq-config
          optional: false
          items:
          - key: enabled_plugins
            path: "enabled_plugins"
          - key: rabbitmq.conf
            path: "rabbitmq.conf"
      - name: rabbitmq-cookie-perm
        secret:
          secretName: erlang-cookie
      - name: rabbitmq-config-rw
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: rabbitmq-cookie
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: rabbitmq-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: rabbitmq-data
      serviceAccount: rabbitmq
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 999
        runAsUser: 999
        runAsGroup: 999
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rabbitmq-config-rw
          mountPath: "/etc/rabbitmq"
        - name: rabbitmq-data
          mountPath: "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia"
        - name: rabbitmq-cookie
          mountPath: "/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie"
          subPath: .erlang.cookie
        env:
        - name: RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME
          value: "true"
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: RABBITMQ_NODENAME
          value: "rabbit@$(MY_POD_NAME).rabbitmq-headless.hi-rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local"
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbitmq-admin
              key: pass
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbitmq-admin
              key: user
        ports:
        - name: amqp
          containerPort: 5672
          protocol: TCP
        - name: management
          containerPort: 15672
          protocol: TCP
        - name: prometheus
          containerPort: 15692
          protocol: TCP
        - name: epmd
          containerPort: 4369
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["rabbitmq-diagnostics", "status"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["rabbitmq-diagnostics", "ping"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 10


apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-config
  namespace: hi-rabbitmq
data:
  enabled_plugins: |
    [rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s, rabbitmq_management, rabbitmq_prometheus].
  rabbitmq.conf: |
    ## Clustering
    cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend  = rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
    cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    cluster_formation.k8s.port = 6443
    cluster_formation.k8s.address_type = hostname
    cluster_formation.node_cleanup.interval = 10
    cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = true
    cluster_partition_handling = autoheal
    cluster_formation.k8s.service_name = rabbitmq-headless
    # queue master locator
    queue_master_locator=min-masters
    # enable guest user
    loopback_users.guest = false

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-headless
  namespace: hi-rabbitmq
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: epmd
    port: 4369
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4369
  - name: cluster-rpc
    port: 25672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 25672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true

When I access the the cluster through port 15672 and a load balancer service, only one node is shown, which is changed every time when refreshed, but when I run
kubectl exec -it kubectl exec -it rabbitmq-master-2 -n hi-rabbitmq rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbitmq-master-0.rabbitmq-headless.hi-rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local
Cluster is formed! There is no problem in this but what will I do when master-0 is down? Like shouldn't it be managed by k8s peer mechanism? Cluster is not formed till I command it!
Tried forming cluster of rabbitmq but failed!
